# How to generate a list of all occurances of a macro?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have some `struct` declarations that are marked with a `COMPONENT` macro. I would like to build a type list from these declarations. Given this code:

```
// a.hpp

COMPONENT(A) {
  // struct body
};

// bc.hpp

COMPONENT(B) {
  // struct body
};
COMPONENT(C) {
  // struct body
};
```

I would like to generate a tuple that looks like this:

```
constexpr auto components = std::make_tuple(
  Comp<A>{“A”},
  Comp<B>{“B”},
  Comp<C>{“C”}
);
```

The order of the elements in the tuple doesn’t matter. I will also have to manually include all the headers that contain `COMPONENT` declarations.

I could write a Python script that generates the file at build time but I would like to do this with the preprocessor if possible. I don’t think this is possible but I’ve seen people do some crazy stuff with the preprocessor so I thought I’d ask. I don’t understand macro meta programming as well as I understand template meta programming.

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do with this information? There might be a better way to achieve what you're ultimately trying to do…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Generic deserialisation. When I read “B” in a file, I know that I must deserialise a B struct.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel In the past I just wrote the list manually. I’d like to automate this with the preprocessor.

Comment: You may wanna have a look at [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Comment: @MichaelKenzel At first glance, protobuf doesn’t seem to support the polymorphism that I can achieve by writing a type list.

Comment: @Kerndog73 _"At first glance, protobuf doesn’t seem to support the polymorphism that I can achieve by writing a type list."_ Well, at least protobuf is able to deal with _extensions_, that's not exactly the same as _polymorphism_ but very similar, and well designed for the definiton of _protocol messages_ and parsing these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with the C preprocessor itself. It is very limited, and doesn't support a full-fledged scripting language - not by a long shot.

Your two courses of action are:

1. Using a compiler's front-end to obtain a pre-preprocessing syntax tree (clang might let you do this; less sure about GCC)
2. Using a Python/Perl/bash/awk/sed script to look for uses of the macro.

Option 1 is much much more effort (unless you can adapt another, existing tool), but accurate; option 2 requires little effort, but is quite inaccurate without "reinventing the wheel" - with false positives (e.g. macro names within strings) and probably also false negatives (e.g. a macro applied within a macro, when its name is generated by concatenating identifiers).